# Can't get doInBackground to work in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm new to AsyncTask so apologies in advance if my problem is silly. Long story short, I have a method that handles some files and I want to run it in the background. My class is below and the problem is that the method works fine when called directly, but absolutely nothing happens when I'm trying to call it via doInBackground.

This works:
`AttachFilesFromFolder.attach(files);`

And this doesn't:
`new AttachFilesFromFolder().execute(files);`

The class in question:

```
public class AttachFilesFromFolder extends AsyncTask<File[], Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(File[]... files) {
        try {
            attach(files[0]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void attach(File[] files) throws InterruptedException {
        for (File file : files) {
            log("For loop started.");
            File targetLocation = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/org.p4.epo.android/" + file.getName());

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;

                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }

                        buf = null;
                        in.close();
                        in = null;
                        out.close();
                        out = null;
                        log("Copied file " + targetLocation.toString() + " successfully.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        SdkManager.sharedInstance().addAttachment(targetLocation.toString(), file.getName(), AttachMode.asNewPage, 1, false);
                        log("Attached " + file.getName());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            log("Thread T1 started.");
            t1.start();
            t1.join();
            log("Thread T2 started.");
            t2.start();
            t2.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work, unless your AsyncTask executor is blocked (probably avoid AsyncTask for new code due to issues like this).  Is your doInBackground method running at all?   Add a log to that.

Comment: Additionally, your current use of `Thread`s is entirely pointless.  You're starting them serially and then immediately joining them, so you're not getting any benefit and just doing extra work.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a log before and it proved that doInBackground isn't running at all. As for my use of threads, the goal is to make sure thread 1 is completed before thread 2 starts.

Comment: Right, but since you're immediately joining them anyway, why not just do all of that work in `doInBackground`?  Why bother with threads at all?

Comment: Are you sure the'll run one after the other in doInBackground? In any case, it looks like the onPreExecute event is triggered properly in my class, but doInBackground isnt. And I get the "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed" error.

Comment: "Are you sure the'll run one after the other in doInBackground?" Yes, code within a method always runs sequentially unless you make it asynchronous somehow, but if it was asynchronous, then your threading approach wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using executeOnExecutor. That worked.